# in Python I need some basic

Tags: python, list

```
name = " "
Age = " "
Gender = " "
people = []
ages = []
while  name != "":
### This is the Raw data input portion and the ablity to stop the program and exit
    name = input("Enter a name or type done:")
    if name == 'done' : break
    Age = input("How old are they?")
    Gender = input("What is their gender M/F?")
### This is where I use .append to create the entry of the list     
    people.append(name)
    people.append(Age)
    ages.append(Age)
    people.append(Gender)
print("list of People:", people)

print(ages)
```

when I get results the list comes out like this

```
list of People: ['jim', '12', 'F', 'Ann', '12', 'F']
['12', '12']
```

how can I remove the '' between each entry  its making me have trouble useing the Mean function to pull a average from the ages list

help !!!

Comment: `Age = int(input('How old are they?'))`

Comment: Thanks that worked

Comment: would you know any code to count number of M and F that get inputed

Comment: `Gender.count('M')`.  Seriously though.. You'll find everything you need in the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that `input` always returns a string. Just use `int` to turn it into an integer:

```
Age = int(input("How old are they?"))
```

But be aware that this will throw a `ValueError`, if you don't enter a number. You can handle the error using a try/except, if you want to. You could cancel the input for the current person and print an error message and then start with a new person:

```
try:
    Age = int(input("How old are they?"))
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input.")
    continue
```